# source of REQUEST

Tags: php, request, httprequest

How do I get the url from which the request was submitted. I tried $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; but this gives me the destination url not the source url. Is it possible to get the origin?

Answer (score 20):

You are looking for [`$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

**Note:**

> The address of the page (if any) which
>   referred the user agent to the current
>   page. This is set by the user agent.
>   Not all user agents will set this, and
>   some provide the ability to modify
>   HTTP_REFERER  as a feature. In short,
>   it cannot really be trusted.

Answer (score 4):

`$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` will work, if it is provided by the calling browser. Note that it is provided by the client so it may be empty or faked, so don't trust it security-wise.