# Source of request in asp.net/C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Basically, I need to know the answer to this question in asp.net/C#:
[source of REQUEST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4118000/source-of-request)
I would like one of my pages to know which page directed the user to this specific page. I've tried going through intellisense on a few different Page properties, but couldn't find it. Any help?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sounds like your looking for `Request.UrlReferrer`

**Documentation:** [HttpRequest.UrlReferrer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.urlreferrer.aspx)

The request can be attained off the page:

```
Page.Request
```

If a Page instance is not available, you can get it from the current context using:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request
```

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for the [`Request.UrlReferrer` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.urlreferrer.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

You can look at `Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_REFERER")` or `Request.ServerVariables("URL")`.

Or you can use the **Request object** this way:

`Request.Url.ToString()` gives you the full path of the calling page.

If you call this in the Immediate Window without the `ToString,` you can see lots of information:

```
Request.UrlReferrer.ToString()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_REFERER"];`

**EDIT:**

Use @SLaks answer

Comment: http://w3fools.com.  Also, you should get the header directly; don't go through ServerVariables.

Comment: i agree. i wasn't aware of UrlReferrer.  that's why i voted for your answer.

Comment: i also was unaware of the backlash against w3schools.  reading over the w3fools site now. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We can get to know the referral Url from UrlReferrer property.
It's easy to handle in the global.asax file.

```
protected void Session_Start()
{
    var SourceURL = HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri.ToString();
}
```

Now we can store this value in session or somewhere and do what ever operation we would like.