# Identify the request source page

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, redirect

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Source of request in asp.net/C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4889971/source-of-request-in-asp-net-c)

I am developing a site in ASP.NET.
I have a special page say default2.aspx and two other page pages default1.aspx, default3.aspx.
The default1.aspx and default3.aspx both have link to default2.aspx.
So on default2.aspx I want to know that from where the request has come.
I think it may be either from typing address in browser ot default1.aspx or default2.aspx.

Does Request object provide any info about it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can use urlreferrer and save it to viewstate

Comment: I don't think it's polite to tell you need the answer ASAP.

Comment: sorry comecme, edited my quetion but I am really in an urgent need for a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Request.UrlReferrer

Hope it helps!